# Combine multiple arrays into a single nested array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like to combine N arrays of shape (I, J) into a single array of shape (I, J, N) such that the value at (i, j, n) in the final array is equal to the value of the n-th array at (i, j).

For example, let's say I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = [[2,3,4],
        [3,4,5]]

arr2 = [[3,4,2],
         [4,3,5]]
```

Then the final array would look like:

```
arr_final == [[[2,3], [3,4], [4,2]], 
              [[3,4], [4,3], [5,5]]]
```

Or, to take a more straightforward example:

```
arr1 = [[0,0,0],
        [0,0,0]]

arr2 = [[1,1,1],
         [1,1,1]]

arr3 = [[2,2,2],
         [2,2,2]]
```

Then the final array would look like:

```
arr_final == [[[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2]], 
              [[0,1,2], [0,1,2], [0,1,2]]]
```

Is there a function in Python, or more specifically Numpy, that could help me with this?

Comment: What does `np.array((arr1, arr2))` produce?  A (2,i,j)?  That's the usual way of combining N arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In Numpy, you can use `numpy.stack`. Remember to specify the axis as -1 in order to get it to correctly compose it as you want according to your question.

```py
import numpy as np

arr_final = np.stack([arr1, arr2, ..., arrN], axis=-1)
```

will produce the desired outcome.